# C programming- printf statement giving "expression expected" error

Tags: c

This is my first posted question, so I apologize in advance if it doesn't make perfect sense.  I am having trouble debugging a snippet of code I wrote.  When attempting to compile the code, I am getting a weird error that is pointing to my printf statements.  Here is the code...

```
int IsItPrime (int number, int *ptr);

int main(void)
{
    int userinput;
    printf ("This program is designed to tell wether or not \na number you enter is prime or composite \nType your number, and press Enter: “);
    scanf ("%i", &userinput);
    int *ptr = &userinput;
    if(IsItPrime(userinput,ptr) == 1)
    {
        printf("The number: %i is a prime number”, userinput);
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("The number: %i is a composite number”, number);
    return 0;
}

int IsItPrime (int number, int *ptr)
{
    int ceiling, i = 0;
    ceiling = number / 2;

    for (i = 2; i <= ceiling; i++)
        if (number % i == 0)
            return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

I've tried everything I could think of at this point.  It is probably something blatantly obvious but I am not too experienced in C. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: In `printf("The number: %i is a composite number”, number);` the variable `number` isn't defined. Perhaps you intended that `printf` to go into your `IsItPrime` function instead of in `main`.

Comment: Your program has weird unicode quote marks - you need to use the standard quote mark `"` instead.  (Don't use word processing software to write program code!)

Answer (score 0):

1. number is local to the function `IsItPrime` you cannot access variable `number` in main function.
2. syntax error `and press Enter: “);` in line 6 (printf statement) and other printf statements

Answer (score 0):

Others already pointed out that numbers cannot be accessed in the main function.

It would be more helpful if you posted your error message.

Anyway, here are two things that might help:

1. Did you include stdio.h ?
2. Never seen that before so not sure, how that happened: But the closing double quotes of the strings are not the normal double quotes but some sort of German or French closing double quotes.

Comment: Yes, I included stdio.h.  The error statement is displaying:

Comment: Solved the problem.  Went to text pad instead of using visual studio (OS X) and retyped everything.  Besides a few logical errors it all worked perfectly fine.  Thanks for the help.